# Any photo gallery library for Android?

Tags: android

Since the built-in photo gallery widget in Android is not good enough (easily crashes), I am looking for a 3rd party photo gallery library ?

Please recommend if you have some good choices.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find something, I have the exact same question!

Comment: See https://android-arsenal.com/tag/48?sort=created (maybe https://github.com/AgnaldoNP/PreviewImageCollection). Also https://androidexample365.com/a-simple-and-easy-to-use-image-preview-android-library/.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few libraries available such as:

- https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow
- https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools

To see more download the following app from the Google play store:
"Android UI Patterns" this app has a lot of examples and you can see them first before implementing.

Also take a look at the GreenDroid also they have a showcase app in Google Play

Comment: Don't look, these libraries are 9-10 years old.

Answer (score 5):

3 years late, but here's a really good library called [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). Uses Picasso along with NineOldAndroids.

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: this Slider is bad, as this it does not allow adjust the height according to content size. the height must be a numeric value.

Comment: @Raptor How would that work if the images added are of different heights? Will the small images have blank spaces above/below them?

Comment: A good slider can handle all sorts of different image sizes in same slider. Resizing method can allow users to choose from aspect fit , fill , center crop , or even leaving white spaces around.

Comment: @Raptor well in that case, the library is open source. create a fork, change it so it adjusts height according to content size and let me know. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one: [image-chooser-library](https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library). It very versatile and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another library is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/). It is much more maintained as the other projects and it is much more flexible. For example, you can show drawable generated in memory.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not a gallery library, but image caching library like Glide, Picasso.