# Looking for a open source picture gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, image-gallery

I'm looking for something like a gallery where I could take some pictures programmatically in. The user should have the right to add another picture - from a given folder - and should have the right to delete a picture. Something like that:

[image]

Is there a opensource gallery or is there a plugin something like that? Would be nice if you have something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose this question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592278/any-photo-gallery-library-for-android)? In any case, there are tonnes of image libraries for Android, here's one called `Picasso': http://square.github.io/picasso/